# Software to Extract and Organize text from Docx

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-word, parser, data-extraction

I have an influx of reports coming at me, and I need to extract some of the data and put it into a better format(an excel worksheet.) The reports come in docx or pdf and look something like this.

```
Miscellaneous data...................    
Unneeded data.......        
             North               South            West
Name         Lakeview Church     Lakeview Church  
Making       Brick               Wood  
Status       Gone                "small checkmark"
unneeded data.......    
Name         Baxter Building                      Baxter Building
Making       Brick                                Brick
Making       Gone                                 Great
```

**But, the text isn't all in tables. Some are, some are just in appropriately placed text boxes.**

I'm kinda going out on a limb here, but I was hoping there would be something that allowed me to make some sort of template that extracted the appropriate data and re organized it something like this:

```
Name               Direction        Making          Status
Lakeview Church    North            Brick           Gone
Lakeview Church    South            Wood            Good
```

Also, there are some small images in the reports. I don't need to extract the images, but if they could be translated into something to show an image was present it would be great. And, if I could tell it to do things like ignoring all things with "Church" in the name on the North side, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

For a coding based solution: [Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) , [Essential DocIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio) can be used to parse PDF and Doc/Docx files respectively. [Essential XlsIO](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/xlsio) can be used to output the structured data to Excel.

[PDF text extraction example](http://asp.syncfusion.com/demos/web/pdf/textextraction.aspx)

[Tables in Word](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/working-with-tables)

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion